# PHP Перевод строки в набор байт и рассчитать md5 от массива

Tags: php, c#, массивы, md5

Есть задача для реализации на ЯП php. Есть входная строка `test{ "md5": "test" }` которую необходимо преобразовать в байтовый массив и рассчитать от него контрольную сумму MD5. Если выполнить данную задачу на ЯП C#, то все правильно рассчитывается:

```
        // входная строка
        string text = "test{ \"md5\": \"test\" }";

        // отобразить входную строку
        Console.WriteLine("{0}[string]{0}{1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, text);

        // массив байтов входной строки
        byte[] text_bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

        // MD5
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        // контрольная сумма масива байтов входной строки
        byte[] checksum_bytes = md5.ComputeHash(text_bytes);

        // результат контрольной суммы строкой
        string checksum = BitConverter.ToString(checksum_bytes);

        // убрать знак "-" из строки контрольной суммы и привести к нижнему регистру
        string result = checksum.Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();

        // отобразить результат
        Console.WriteLine("{0}[checksum]{0}{1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, result);
```

массив байт ЯП C#: `array (21) {[0] => int(116)[1] => int(101)[2] => int(115)[3] => int(116)[4] => int(123)[5] => int(32)[6] => int(34)[7] => int(109)[8] => int(100)[9] => int(53)[10] => int(34)[11] => int(58)[12] => int(32)[13] => int(34)[14] => int(116)[15] => int(101)[16] => int(115)[17] => int(116)[18] => int(34)[19] => int(32)[20] => int(125)} ddeaa8f6abb9b39a8d9a18516630f150`

Реализация на ЯП php дает иной результат:

```
    // входная строка
    $text = 'test{ "md5": "test" }'; 

    // массив байтов входной строки
    $bytes = unpack("C*", $text);

    // контрольная сумма массива байтов
    $md = md5(json_encode($bytes));

    // отобразить результат
    var_dump($md);
```

Результат: `array (21) {[1] => int (116) [2] => int (101) [3] => int (115) [4] => int (116) [5] => int (123) [6] => int (32) [7] => int (34) [8] => int (109) [9] => int (100) [10] => int (53) [11] => int (34) [12] => int (58) [13] => int (32) [14] => int (34) [15] => int (116) [16] => int (101) [ 17] => int (115) [18] => int (116) [19] => int (34) [20] => int (32) [21] => int (125)} строка (32) " b10fe47fad22f72c10df47ce4b85e234 "`

Почему контрольная сумма массива рассчитывается неправильно?

Comment: я вам удивлю немного, наверное, но `md5($text)` дает вам искомый хэш без всяких танцев, особенно с не пойми зачем приплетенным json_encode

Comment: вы вообще можете объяснить, зачем добавлять `\0` к строке, а затем отрезать его в array_slice ?

Comment: опечатка с прошлого кода, исправил. Результат на PHP: array (21) {[1] => int (116) [2] => int (101) [3] => int (115) [4] => int (116) [5] => int (123) [6] => int (32) [7] => int (34) [8] => int (109) [9] => int (100) [10] => int (53) [11] => int (34) [12] => int (58) [13] => int (32) [14] => int (34) [15] => int (116) [16] => int (101) [ 17] => int (115) [18] => int (116) [19] => int (34) [20] => int (32) [21] => int (125)} строка (32) " b10fe47fad22f72c10df47ce4b85e234 "

Comment: Все равно не сходится

Comment: что не сходится то? `echo md5('test{ "md5": "test" }')` выводит искомый  `ddeaa8f6abb9b39a8d9a18516630f150`

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно на PHP не нужно было распаковывать в массив строку. Как + тебе поставить?)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо пользователю [teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223826/teran). В PHP не нужно было распаковывать строку в массив.

```
// входная строка
$text = 'test{ "md5": "test" }'; 

// контрольная сумма
$md = md5($text);

// отобразить результат
var_dump($md);
```